# File host for android App

Tags: java, android, mobile, dropbox, google-sites

I am trying to put the last couple of pieces of the puzzle together for this project for my mobile apps class, and have hit a bit of a wall. Basically this is an application for a fictional restaurant. The restaurant can put things into a menu stored on the web(currently on dropbox) and those items in the file will show up on the mobile app. The customer can then order items from the menu and the restaurant can view these in another file.

I have already finished the desktop application, and the majority of the mobile app. All I have left to do is to download the file from dropbox and use that info to update the variables. The problem is I am having trouble finding a way to download the file to the mobile app without having to log into dropbox every time.

I am new to having to use outside hosting like this, but I do know java pretty well. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Feel free to ask questions as well.

Comment: You must share the link and then use it in the download! So: URL url = new URL("link shared");
   HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

Comment: Thanks! This will at least get the menu downloaded. Would that allow me to edit a file as well? I still need to have the app write to a file that lists the orders.

Comment: I do not know, but I find it impossible to edit a file that is in the dropbox. Unless you have a dropbox folder on your phone then fetch the file in that folder and edit.